# Trait method with generic argument

Tags: rust, async-await

The following code provides a container in which to store prepared functions for asynchronous code so that you can pass it somewhere for execution:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use futures::future::{Future, BoxFuture};


trait AsyncFn {
    fn call(&self, arg: String) -> BoxFuture<'static, ()>;
}

impl<T, F> AsyncFn for T
where
    T: Fn(String) -> F,
    F: Future<Output = ()> + 'static + Send,
{
    fn call(&self, arg: String) -> BoxFuture<'static, ()> {
        Box::pin(self(arg))
    }
}

async fn async_test(data: String) -> () {
    println!("{data}");
}

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut callables: HashMap<String, Box<dyn AsyncFn>> = HashMap::new();
    callables.insert("test_func".to_string(), Box::new(async_test));

    let awaitable = callables.get("test_func").unwrap();
    awaitable.call("test string argument1".to_string()).await;
    let awaitable = callables.get("test_func").unwrap();
    awaitable.call("test string argument2".to_string()).await;
}
```

But this greatly limits the set of functionality called in this way. I can only pass strings.
Is it possible to describe the trait more universally, so that AsyncFn can accept a heap reference to any type?

I tried to do it like this:

```rust
trait AsyncFn<B> {
    fn call(&self, arg: Box<B>) -> BoxFuture<'static, ()>;
}

impl<T, B, F> AsyncFn<B> for T
where
    T: Fn(Box<B>) -> F,
    F: Future<Output = ()> + 'static + Send,
{
    fn call(&self, arg: Box<B>) -> BoxFuture<'static, ()> {
        Box::pin(self(arg))
    }
}

async fn async_test(data: Box<String>) -> () {
    println!("String data = {data}");
}
async fn async_test2(data: Box<u64>) -> () {
    println!("u64 data = {data}");
}
```

But this still restricts the type that I send to the container:

```rust
let mut callables: HashMap<String, Box<dyn AsyncFn<String>>> = HashMap::new();

callables.insert("test_func".to_string(), Box::new(async_test));
// ! callables.insert("test_func2".to_string(), Box::new(async_test2));
```

I should probably try wrapping this in an enum or some other type, but maybe there is a more elegant solution?

Comment: You can store a `Box<dyn Any>`, if you make sure to send the correct parameter type.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I get an error: `the trait std::marker::Send is not implemented for (dyn std::any::Any + 'static)`

Comment: So you need `Box<dyn Any + Send>`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Exactly, it's that simple. Thanks a lot! This works great.